# Raspberry Pi Zero SSH over USB publickey permissions error

Tags: ssh, pi-zero

I've been trying to communicate with my Raspberry Pi 0 through SSH over micro-USB, but haven't gotten very far.

Typically, I can do it remotely by wirelessly connecting with `ssh pi@zumidashboard.ai`. However, when I try that here, I get this error.

[image]

I've tried disabling Pubkey Authentication and enabling Password Authentication in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and then rebooting, but no luck.

I would like password authentication to work and for the Pi to stop trying to use keys. I do not know what else I need to change to get this.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome.  Please edit into your question: 1) The relevant bits of `sshd_config` from the pi, 2) The output from trying to connect with the `-v` switch (ie., `ssh -v ...`).  It would be much better if you cut 'n' paste that rather than post a screenshot.

Comment: From what I can see of your Question (post TEXT) you are using macOS and this is a macOS error. It has nothing to do with ssh keys on the Pi.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not followed up on the comments. It's reasonable to assume that the OP has "left the building", and as no one else is showing interest in this problem, it should be closed.